# Automatically fix missing parenthesis in C

Tags: c++, c, fortran, warnings, parentheses

I converted some Fortran code to C. I was wondering if someone could help me solve the following problem:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
```

I know this warning is caused by syntax like this:

```
A || B && C
```

Which should be written as:

```
A || (B && C)
```

My compiler is able to compile the code since && has a higher priority than || so it just imagines the parentheses.

The problem is that this warning occurs about 30.000 times since I'm working on a large project.

**Is there any tool that is able to insert the parenthesis around all the && automatically?**

Comment: If you want to be absolutely certain, I'm affraid, that you would have to implement a C code parser to achieve this...

Comment: Really? 30.000 times? How many lines does you project have? Or is the same warning displayed several times due to headers that are included by different modules? Then the cost of changing the stuff by hand might not be so bad.

Comment: How did you convert from Fortran to C? Sounds like you need to fix that step.

Comment: try to use include guards maybe it can help not seeing so may warnings.

Comment: are all the operands of the `&&` the same?

Comment: Koushik, yes, all the warnings are caused by &&. But the operands are different.
DavidHeffernan, i used f2c
RalphTandetzky, yes it's huge! :-)
Spook, what kind of parser do you suggest?

Comment: i frankly don't understand why this even deserves a warning, does your compiler suggest adding superfluous parenthesis to algebraic expressions too?

Comment: Yes @george, it does. I was wondering, since i work with Visual Studio is it possible to do the trick with a certain Macro?

Comment: @user2470258 *"Yes, it does"* - Really? I would at best be deeply insulted (and at least extremely annoyed) if the compiler thought me that stupid to not allow me writing `a + b*c`. Those compilers can indeed get rather extreme with their idiot warnings and sometimes (though not always, I agree) you should just trust the programmer to have understood the most basic of language rules.

Comment: @george: it deserves a warning because it's a really common human error to type things like `A||B && C`, and mentally have the `A||B` binding tighter.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said do it manually, also you can disable this warning using `-Wno-parentheses`, even though that's pretty dangerous

Comment: no more dangerous  than automatically adding parenthesis without studying the code.

Answer (score -1):

Turn off stupid warnings. `A || B && C` does **not** need parentheses, any more than `A + B * C` does. Unless you haven't bothered to learn how logical expressions work...